# How to find and replace empty values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

for the example, I have an array

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "0"
        [1] => "1"
    )
[1] => 
[2] => Array
    (
        [4] => "4"
        [5] => "5"
        [7] => "7"
    )
```

and I want to find empty array value, and replace it.

```
[1] => data not found
```

Comment: Recursive or just the first level? If it's just the first level then you can just map it. `$array = array_map(function($value) { if (empty($value) return 'data not found'; return $value; }, $array);`

Comment: first level, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Non-recursive:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "0",
        1 => "1"
    ),
    1 => "",
    2 => array(
        4 => "4",
        5 => "5",
        7 => "7"
    ),
    3 => array(
        8 => "",
        9 => ""
    )
);

foreach($arr as &$val){
if($val === "" || $val === false || $val === null) $val = "data not found";
}

print_r($arr);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/133000)

### Recursive:

```
function replace_empty_values($arr){
    foreach($arr as &$val){
    if(is_array($val)) $val = replace_empty_values($val);
    else if($val === "" || $val === false || $val === null) $val = "data not found";
    }
return $arr;
}

$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "0",
        1 => "1"
    ),
    1 => "",
    2 => array(
        4 => "4",
        5 => "5",
        7 => "7"
    ),
    3 => array(
        8 => "",
        9 => ""
    )
);

$arr = replace_empty_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/133002)

Comment: Note that if the value is "0", 0, that is still considered empty. **Edit:** +1 for changing it to checking for "", false, or null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution.

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "0",
        1 => "1"
    ),
    1 => "",
    2 => array(
        4 => "4",
        5 => "5",
        7 => "7"
    )
);

function removeEmpty($arr){
    if(is_array($arr)){
        foreach($arr as &$val){
             $val = removeEmpty($val);
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    else {
        if(empty($arr) && $arr != "0") return "data not found";
    }
}

print_r(removeEmpty($myArray));
```